# Uncaught SoapFault Exception [Http] Internal Server Error

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm developing an API(PHP) to communicate using SOAP with other client, connecting with the client is perfectly fine but when i call a function i receive this error message:

*"Uncaught SoapFault Exception [Http] Internal Server Error..."*

At first I thought I just miss a required field but as I continue my test I receive the same error. The web service was develop by other company and there's no way in modifying it. This is also my 1st time in using web service.

My question is how can i extract the error so i can easily resolve the problem? Does the "Internal Server Error" means a client fault or a server fault?

Thanks!

Regards,
Sonny

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this error shown when you didnt install soap on your server or vps so

check soap installed correctly on your server you should add soap extension and recompile php

i did this before with directadmin panel

[install soap on directadmin](http://woshka.com/blog/linux/centos/direct-admin-control-panel/compile-and-enable-soap-into-php-with-directadmin-controlpanel-custombuild.html)

its a model u can search for your panel like cpanel and ....